# Disable task for code-generation in test for google's KSP

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-symbol-processing

I've a multi-module project using [google's KSP](https://github.com/google/ksp) version 1.8.10-1.0.9 and it would be helpful if someone can help me with disabling the task of code-generation in the tests sub-directory of the build directory.

This is roughly the structure of the project:

````bash
myProject
    - api
    - engine
    - methods
        - build.gradle.kts
            ```
            dependencies {
                implementation(project(":engine"))
                implementation(project(":methodsProcessor"))

                testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
                testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":engine")))

                testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.8.2")

                ksp(project(":methodsProcessor"))
            }
        ```
        - build
            - generated
                - ksp
                    - main
                        - kotlin
                            - methods
                                - PublicMethods.kt

                    - test   ##  I don't want this directory to be created at all
                        - kotlin
                            - methods
                                - PublicMethods.kt
    - methodsProcessor
        - build.gradle.kts (contents below)
            ```
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ksp.api)
            }
            ```
        - src.main.kotlin.processor.MethodsProcessor
            ## this file has a SymbolProcessor which creates a new file (PublicMethods.kt) in
            ## `methods/build/generated/ksp/main/kotlin/methods` &
            ## `methods/build/generated/ksp/test/kotlin/methods` (THIS I would like not to be created)
    - build.gradle.kts
    - settings.gradle.kts
        ```
            rootProject.name = "myProject"

            include("engine")
            include("methods")
            include("api")
            include("methodsProcessor")

            val kotlinVersion: String by settings
            val kspVersion: String by settings

            pluginManagement {
                plugins {
                    // For some reason the global variables are not accessible here
                    val kotlinVersion: String by settings
                    val kspVersion: String by settings
                    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
                    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version kotlinVersion
                    kotlin("plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
                    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version kspVersion
                }
            }

            dependencyResolutionManagement {
                repositories {
                    mavenCentral()
                }
                versionCatalogs {
                    create("libs") {
                        library("ksp-api", "com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:$kspVersion")
                    }
                }
            }
            ```
````

When I run `./gradlew build` for my project, the output on the terminal looks like:

```bash
> Task :api:openApiGenerate
################################################################################
# Thanks for using OpenAPI Generator.                                          #
# Please consider donation to help us maintain this project                  #
# https://opencollective.com/openapi_generator/donate                          #
################################################################################
Successfully generated code to /Users/gxyd/projects/solver-engine/api/build/generated-src/openapi

> Task :methods:kspKotlin
w: [ksp] hello world

Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build after running out of JVM memory

> Task :methods:kspTestKotlin
w: [ksp] hello world
```

So, the second task that you see, i.e. `:methods:kspTestKotlin` is something I don't to it to run.

I've already tried having the below configuration in `methods.build.gradle.kts`:

```
ksp {
    tasks.named("kspTestKotlin") {
        enabled = false
    }
}
```

which raises the error saying, there is no task named "kspTestKotlin", while building my project.

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `ksp` configuration applies to all source sets, while the other configurations (like `kspTest`) only apply to specific ones.

Starting from KSP 1.0.1, there is a property that allows you to enable this behavior for the `ksp` configuration as well. Simply add the following to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
ksp.allow.all.target.configuration=false
```

With this, the `ksp` configuration will only apply to the main source set. Starting from KSP 2.0, the `ksp` configuration will behave like this by default.

This is documented here: [KSP with Kotlin Multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-multiplatform.html#avoid-the-ksp-configuration-on-ksp-1-0-1)

The documentation is for multiplatform, but this applies to single-platform projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I was missing JUnit engine dependency:

```
testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junit}"
```